# Extract Access database objects and load them in SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, powershell, etl

I want to programmatically read all **database objects** from an Access database and then link/store them to a SQL server database. The data needs to be interfaced on a daily base.

What would be the best approach from the below:

1. Read records from different tables and update fields in SQL server accordingly.
2. Delete all tables on the SQL Server database and recreate everything from scratch.

I was thinking to implement this using PowerShell. There are 2 parts. One is reading the catalog/DB structure using the ADOX library and the second part is storing the data (and/or) the schema in the SQL server database. At this point, I do not have a clue on how to convert the ADOX data to SQL server. Any thoughts/recommendations on this?

Many thanks.

Comment: This could be a good way to get started: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.05.scriptingguys.aspx

Comment: You can apparently use SSMA (SQL Server Migration Assistant) as a command-line application. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313087%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) for details.